# Could there be an "obviously competent" concept, clickable by hr users?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A very high rep user, would be able to **click something** to give **starter points** (say, 100) to **obviously highly competent** but brand-new users.

For example there might be a button on answers **"Professional answer by new user."**

So,

-- this can only be done if you have 10k+

-- the "new, expert" user gets 100 points

-- it costs the hr user 200 points to do this action (suggested by OGHaza)

## Purpose:

The raison d'être of points as they exist, is that **it helps you identify "hopeless and transitory" users**. The scheme suggested here would strengthen this.

(There are other minor purposes of points. For example: *"allowing long-time users to be able to moderate"*.  These aspects of points would be utterly unaffected by the proposal. You're only talking 100 points to lift someone from the (let's put it offensively!!) "newbie idiot look".)

## Additional minor benefits:

Site would be less annoying for experts coming freshly to the site.

Indeed, and here's an interesting point ...... good-minded brand new users **would work hard** to make their first few q/a be of really high quality, since they might luck out with a **"Professional answer by new user"** click.

PS, it occurs to me I guess it would be a badge.  "You got a 'Professional answer by new user' click." That would be a fun badge because you could ONLY get it when you had less than 100 points, once in your career.  Once again, conceivably, some good-minded brand new users would work hard to make their first few q/a be of really high quality, to try to get that.

Other titles for this badge/button/feature/concept could be:

**Nice contribution by new user**

**100-points-of-quality new user bonus**

**Very good answer by very new user**

**New user but top quality bonus**

**Nice contribution in the first week**

**Newbie-but-a-goodie bonus**

You could easily make it quite gamey by, for example, making it that you can ONLY get the "Nice by new user" award/badge in say the FIRST THREE DAYS using the site.  With luck, that would really push people to work hard to contribute quality material, so as to get it.  (And it gives newbies a nice feeling, "even someone with 100k can't ever get this".)

Note that this actually REWARDS AND ENCOURAGES newbies rather than just hating on them.

Cheers

Comment: *"There's no downside"* You mean, other than the potential for rampant abuse?

Comment: There are plenty of downsides. People really suck at evaluating their own skill.

Comment: @Benjamin.  I'm saying A HIGH REP USER (say, you) would be able to click that button on the activity of a NEW user.  It's amazing my post was not clear, I'll edit it.

Comment: No one said your post wasn't clear. They said it was a bad idea. What in your proposal would stop a high-rep user from just giving points to their friends?

Comment: What is "obviously highly competent"?

Comment: @JoeBlow your post was clear, we just don't really think it's a good idea, reputation isn't a measure of expertise but a measure of site participation.

Comment: Hey @william, (a) on the topic (e.g. "android programming") the person is obviously an expert and (b) in terms of using a QA site, the person is obviously competent.  So, allow me to copy and paste, "In most cases (80%?) NBOEP is (a) a beginner programmer and (b) staggeringly unskilled at using QA sites (i.e., asks horrible, poorly-formatted, duplicate questions and so on)."

Comment: Hey @benjamim (who is "we"?  do you work for SO?  if so, awesome) Can you **explain the downsides**, please?

Comment: You did not answer my question. Anyhow, an "obviously highly competent" user will make reputation really fast by providing high quality answers.

Comment: you say "reputation isn't a measure of expertise but a measure of site participation". That's an interesting viewpoint; I struggle to see it though. The purpose of reputation on QA sites is: **to let you quickly see who is a newbie idiot**. i.e., along with social indicators like "grammar", "QA site competence", "understanding of technical terms in the field" and so on.  The proposal above would reinforce that.  (There are also other purposes to rep scores on QA sites, like "enabling moderating to increase pro-sumption value by long-time users" and so on.)

Comment: @william - I think you're asking for a definition of the word "obvious". usual dictionary definition

Comment: I think you're looking for the definition of the word "[fallacy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fallacy)", usual dictionary definition.

Comment: Hi william, sorry I don't have time for word games or humour.  I believe what you're trying to express is: "I feel it's not possible to 'obviously' tell who is a expert user." It's extremely easy for me, and anyone I have knowledge of, to easily and instantly tell who is an expert user.  Social-linguistic clues include expert handling of terms, fast and detailed explanations of points struggled with by others in the conversation, and so on.  It's so, well, obvious, that humans are good at this that I wouldn't have time to debate it with you, cheers.

Comment: 1 rep users can't upvote. There would be plenty of users going around answering quick fire terrible questions finishing with "here's 200 rep to get you started, now you can upvote posts that are useful to you". Unless I've misunderstood and the rep would transfer from the high rep user.

Comment: Hey that's **a great idea** - the rep would come from the user.  Cheers

Comment: *"Often when this happens, I'll click around manually and make sure the NBOEP has at least a few points, so they don't walk off in annoyance"* : Please don't. Upvote questions and answers only for their own merit. Especially answers as votes are used to make useful answers more visible to people having similar problems.

Comment: hi @dystroy - to be sure to be sure, i only vote up an answer if the answer in itself is superb!  same with bounties.

Comment: Competence in specific subject matter does not mean a user is competent where it concerns the site's rules/regulations, what's on and off-topic, what these votes should be used for, etc. Sure, the hurdles are, well, hurdles. But if you're really all that competent, overcoming them, and learning about the site in the process, should not be all that hard. That is what I don't see downsides to.

Comment: Really confusing post... you talk about `hr` and `NBOEP` as if people should know what they mean, only well down in the text one can understand. Tip: do not add edits as separate stuff, consolidate your text as fluid as possible; this way, people who arrive late can get it at once.

Comment: Wow, wayyyy better ;)

Comment: lol it's not a writing contest :)  But you gave me a great idea ... "conceivably, some good-minded brand new users would work hard to make their first few q/a be of really high quality, to try to get that"  that's true

Answer (score 16):

If the professional user cannot quickly make it past the rep barricades, he/she must not be as professional as you make him/her out to be. One good answer does not prove he/she is capable of handling the higher-rep privileges in a decent manner. This is something acquired by experiencing the site and its users, which naturally comes when one participates on the site, by asking and answering questions.

---

Now, say, the high-rep user needs to have, 3000 rep to perform this action. This would make you eligible on Meta.

This rep requirement should signify that the high-rep user in question understands how the site works, and that he can judge others on their knowledge of how the site works.

Now for the reason why this is a bad idea: you, with 3000 rep, seem to fail to understand how Meta question votes work. How can we entrust such self-proclaimed " site experts" to judge or "back" newcomers?

It seems a rather self-destructing idea.

Comment: Thanks for actually providing an answer.  TBC I would imagine you'd need (say) 20k? to perform such an action.  Regarding your pointlessly snarky attempt at humour in the penultimate paragraph, it adds utterly nothing to your argument.  An example ("Joe does not understand something I do about this site") does not make good argument.

Comment: "... cannot quickly make it past ..."  sure, but the whole point here is "it's not quick enough.  To put it another way: it's a bit ridiculous seeing someone who's obviously competent, having 12 points.  Further: as I say in the comments above the whole raison d'être of the points system is so that you can be helped to instant recognised "passing newbie jokers". This would help in that.  I sense that there's an almost "moral" outlook to your position: "We all had to *work* for them points, why shouldn't others!" I find it hard to buy that; it's just a site for engineers to get jobs done.

Comment: @Joe It's perfect proof reputation shows nothing about the user's understanding of the site, let alone their ability to judge others by reading _one_ answer. I didn't mean it as a personal attack, mind you, but it was a nice example of how reputation is quite meaningless without the actions and experience to back it up. Some get rep undeserved, or by luck (by answering popular topical questions fast), and that is sad. But giving those users the privilege to push others into a more powerful position? No.

Comment: Also, Stackoverflow is not "a site for engineers to get jobs done". From the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page: `Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.`

Comment: Hi Ruben, your example is that me (in the example) does not understand some fine, detailed point about the site.  In the real world, say you're an android guy, when you're looking at QA on the site you can instantly tell who is (a) an android expert (even if 12 points) and (b) completely competent at using a QA site properly (even if 12 points).

Comment: Yes we totally can do that with our Obviously Competent Crystal Ball™

Comment: SO is, in fact **"a pro-sumption site for engineers to get jobs done"**. (And yes, hobbyist programmers, also.) That's an accurate description of the site. What you quoted was a mission statement by the founders of the business about what they wanted, hoped, whatever, the business would become.  Anyway thanks again for your input - I have to go back to doing math :)

Comment: That's awesome how you can quote inside comments like that!  Who knew??

Comment: @JoeBlow perhaps part of this issue here is that you are too good a user. That is, you see this feature as something you the expert, will use to do good for this great person you know you can trust, as well as for the site. But what about user X who doesn't care all that much about this process? Who has figured out that his 10k lets him invite user Y over, who isn't all that competent, but doesn't really want to bother with those pesky hurdles? How do you deal with that?

Comment: Bart I just think that the problem you describe: every single feature (everything, every single feature) on SO can have that problem.  It just doesn't strike me as a big deal. In the scheme (maybe) experts would be happier using the site and (most importantly) it would be slightly easier to distinguish "useless and just-passing users". The whole point of points is if someone has 12 points, you know they're probably just a useless or passing user.  The idea here is, the scheme suggested would reinforce that.

Comment: Regarding how I personally would abuse the process, obviously I'd sell them for money! :)

Answer (score 13):

There are plenty of 10k+ users who are, in my eyes, not ideal users. Some got there by winning the SO lottery, some got there by answering everything they can no matter how bad the question is. This alone is reason enough to not do this.

Second, this is open for abuse. User A has 10k rep. User B is a friend of User A and is new to the site. *Oh, let me give you a quick 250 reputation to let you skip all these annoying limitations!*

Lastly, this is actually already possible in the form of bounties. If you really think that a new user is a highly competent user, you can spend some of your own rep to give it to said user if they post an answer.

Comment: HI @Stijn -- thanks for that answer.  Cody mentioned "abuse" with no explanation - is this what you meant, Cody?

Comment: I do find it incredible that anyone would consider this "abuse". (I must be not understanding something.)  I don't mean this in a mean way, but my 6 year old child might talk about **"Someone on DragonQuest CHEATED and got TWELVE POINTS!"**  In your actual example, I think that would be a great idea, Stijn.  User B would almost always be a competent expert and hence User B would be less likely to look like newbie-fluff. Exactly as you say, "B" would sip the limitations.  The limitations only exist to stop total idiot beginners slightly ruining the site.

Comment: @JoeBlow But who's to say that User B is not a *total idiot beginner*, as you put it?

Comment: To be perfectly clear, I'm talking about adding a couple hundred points - specifically to lift over the "newbie idiot" level.  I'm not talking about adding enough points that the user can do anything serious (2k, or whatever that is).  And surely - surely - it's inconceivable anyone could care about the points "competition" aspect below a few hundred points?  (for civilians reading - some top SO users are competitive about the "points score" on SO).

Comment: Hi Stijn -- almost always, because "A" is high-rep person, the "recommendation" would be completely normal and righteous.  Note that **every single transaction**, and **every aspect of** SO is subject to the problem you mention.  Every split second votes go to the wrong person, bounties are awarded incoherently, etc etc.  Anyways thanks for supplying an actual answer, cheers for now

Answer (score 12):

**NO.**

If expert users are interested in collecting rep, they will easily get to 250. Meanwhile they hopefully familiarize themselves with the site culture and rules. We do not need more people who think this site is about them and their opinion easily overwrites any rule here. Show that you can and are willing to participate, and you are more than welcome.

Also this feature can be so easily abused:

- It would create a sock-puppeteer paradise. Easier than ever, you simply grant your minions 250 rep and they are already quite capable.
- Most people here cannot separate their personal feelings and professional life. If a friend or colleague (or even someone in comments) asked them they would be unable to say no, regardless of the expertise of the person asking. Imagine the situation, saying no would mean they think the other is not good enough. Some people do not even downvote *people they never met*, just not to hurt their feelings!
- Even among highreps we have some who do not understand how the site works or think they are bigger than the community. They already abuse anything the site gives them. Imagine some of them randomly throwing around starter rep just for the fun of revolution :). Or a new trend. Attention-whores are not to be underestimated.

**Note:** People who have a certain amount of rep (don't remember the exact number) on a Stack Exchange site will already get 100 rep when they sign up for a different one. They already had the chance to familiarize themselves with the Q&A format, they can be trusted with some basic privileges.

Comment: Thanks for the clear comments, Kap.  "If expert users are interested in collecting rep, they will easily get to 250."  I guess in a sense that's the fundamental objection here.   BTW I guess sock-puppets could be taken care of via "it costs the hr user 250 points to do this action".  (Just FWIW, on a point of logic, your earlier claim that it's "easily" to get to 250, makes the sock puppet concern pointless.)

Comment: @joeblow 250 points is a very cheap price for a sockpuppet. They will earn much more in return. My earlier claim does not make the concern pointless, unless you want to understand it like that. Which you can freely do, but I would prefer to spend time on real arguments.

Answer (score 2):

### This isn't a new feature, it already exists, sort-of:

Bounties could easily be abused this way, so it must happen.  But don't do that.

And setting up a bounty question to be miraculously answered by a friend takes time....

#### But what if the friend needs to get on SO right now!?

They don't.  The friends could discuss the question that needs to be posted and if they can't solve it themselves, then the person with the account could post.

#### Corporations might decide they own your rep.

After all, if you are asking questions at work, and getting rep, it is really theirs and so you can give it to your boss or the new guy, right?

Suddenly, what was a job-portable artifact of your work experience is instead a hassle for you and a resource to be drained by them

Let's not go there.

Comment: As outstanding point, Paul.  Indeed I continually give out bounties to get rid of my points, because it's trendy to have low points and superb answers are sometimes not rewarded enough.  I suppose if I gave one to a new expert user that's an example of that.